# Can't get styled components to center logo in center of screen?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am not sure if it's with the component structure or what if somebody could explain that this is only like my 2nd week using react, and second time using styled components.

Sorry if this is something simple.. 
I was looking at this code pen which is basically what I am trying to achieve.. 
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/pixelgiant/pen/QKOEdq?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=28818bf7a742d14548babffc7c7d53bf71a1f67c-1588639925-0-AZcGZWA7qhrVyyj-rHtUQuKFJt0A4BLFW4LfjaNKwUdCWpfrO1eLdxHfrWspOhBIGymTC_1LjisHhfLgZimLEeTV-AreXfUVXsQ_lbsgi8KWSWwrFtJ3cno-QQDy8Ysj2LiT-_x5VfVYzboHpOr39kHDPuYeqMLm0qNXhj7lzQ9bzSy2ApxrxF4lhMHWc69qRxtm-1uLeE3z9XU1S7z5s1ov784ecbRs0PK5imixOAWflmNvZLzpQmruxVTLXBxzfcmWgtxVDSIcy20QXm5XYEt8W-bmJKrtliYY245ZEJyaovNnMuRksZ2S7_FXCX45qF90rkeJY03FusHRKtgRk9hgh9GYVfK_luB1YmKkZJSnoRS18k12NlIn8y-4Hy6D9p8tE3fy1zIsgUZlTtq79pJJieu_9wxGSv2eqZMaSk1KigTC6VtJmoWeli3LxNVaAaYN094UUpR9QwAqdZAwrU8XFmSnWx0Dj-fTDXCYrBBVPBWAlDjy_tP1OPUCf2NWtdtRRICvol4NC3rNU-_P5PMT-HSDjFqbMTfTGEmItFWlrY9rlWtnX_UzksdjVIT8xzWRx_ieoU8T2qgCTaBEScU)

Here is the file :

Home.js -

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components";
import Background from './images/Cryptid.png'
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'


const Home = () => {

    return (

        <Container>
            <GlobalStyle />
            <InnerContainer>
                <Logo />
                <JoinInfo><p>test</p></JoinInfo>
            </InnerContainer>
        </Container>
    )


}

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    background: black;
  }`


const OutterContainer = styled.div`
display: flex;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
`;

const InnerContainer = styled.div`

height: 100%;
width: 100%;
`;

const Logo = styled.div`
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
border: 1px solid red;
/* margin: auto;
padding: auto; */
height: 100px;
width: 400px;
background-image: url(${ Background});
`

const JoinInfo = styled.section`

  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
color: white;
`
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`justify-content` and `align-items` are the correct properties however they should be placed on the container and they will be applied to the children.

Let's create a container to wrap the logo in. We'll use the flex properties and some others.

```js
const LogoContainer = styled.div`
display: flex;
justify-content:center; // centers in the flex direction and the default flex-direction is row
align-items:center; // centers perpendicular to the flex direction
height: 100vh; // 100% view height
width: 100vw; // 100% view width
position: absolute; // so it goes behind the current content
`;
```

You can learn more about css flexbox at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

Comment: How okay awesome, but how would I go about getting it center of the page like that. Like in the middle of the whole viewport? Thanks for the help tonight, you're active ha!

Answer (score 0):

```
const InnerContainer = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
```

simply change your inner container. and you need to know more about flex.